# Unable to runhaskell my wxHaskell program that works in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, wxhaskell

I am trying to create a HelloWorld.exe on Windows 7 that demonstrates a very simple wxHaskell program I have found online.  The code is below:

```
module HelloWorldWX where
import Graphics.UI.WX

main :: IO ()
main
  = start hello

hello :: IO ()
hello = do
       f    <- frame    [text := "Hello!"]
       quit <- button f [text := "Quit", on command := close f]
       set f [layout := widget quit]
```

in a file called HelloWorldWX.hs.  I downloaded the binary distribution of wxHaskell (wxInstall-Achelanne-64-0.1).  After running Install.bat I noticed it used Cabal to set up a new package location where it installed wx-0.92.0.1 and all of its depedencies.  The first time it ran it failed for some non-specified reason.  I ran `ghc-pkg list` and found all of the packages were listed in the new cabal package location.  I decided to unregister all of the packages and try again.  This second time it was successful and prompted me to include the following directories in my search path which I did:

> C:\Users...\Downloads\wxInstall-Achelanne-64-0.1\DLLs;C:\Users...\Downloads\wxInstall-Achelanne-64-0.1\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll

At this point when I loaded HelloWorldWX.hs into GHCI and ran main, I got the window frame with the Quit button like I expect.

I then compiled the .hs file into a .o file.  I then attempted to create an executable with the following command:

```
ghc -v -o HelloWorldWX HelloWorldWX.o

Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.10.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.10.2
Using binary package database: C:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\pack
age.conf.d\package.cache
Using binary package database: C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw
32-7.10.3\package.conf.d\package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.4.0.0-428c198583a031a3ea42dd32ae6
f9bab
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.0.0-3c8c40657a9870f5c33be
17496806d8d
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.8.2.0-14035a44a8b95c6832da6dae1420f59e
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.10.0.0-bcb07fec12
f32563bb45d7fb009640b1
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-7.10.3-7a0d3c701e4b1d1f2c3f3bd2deae9bed
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags:
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0
*** C Compiler:
"C:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe" "-fno-stack-
protector" "-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE" "-c" "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\g
hc13152_0\ghc_1.c" "-o" "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_2.
o" "-IC:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/include"
*** Windres:
"C:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/../mingw/bin/windres.exe" "--prepr
ocessor=\"C:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe\" \"
-fno-stack-protector\" \"-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE\" \"-E\" \"-xc\" \"-DRC_INVOKED\"
" "--use-temp-file" "--input=C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\gh
c_4.rc" "--output=C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_5.o" "--o
utput-format=coff"
*** Linker:
"C:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe" "-fno-stack-
protector" "-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE" "-Wl,--hash-size=31" "-Wl,--reduce-memory-ove
rheads" "-Xlinker" "--stack=0x800000,0x800000" "-static-libgcc" "-o" "HelloWorld
WX.exe" "-Wl,--enable-auto-import" "HelloWorldWX.o" "C:\Users\...\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_5.o" "-LC:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\b
ase_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM" "-LC:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\inte
g_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS" "-LC:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\ghcpr_
8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3" "-LC:\Users\...\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/rts" "C:
\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_2.o" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziT
ypes_Izh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,ghcz
mprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info"
"-Wl,-u,base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Wzh_static_i
nfo" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_
info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I64zh_stati
c_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W16zh_st
atic_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W64z
h_static_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim
_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info" "-Wl,-u,ghc
zmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info" "-Wl,
-u,base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info" "-Wl,-u,ba
se_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info" "-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure" "
-Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_c
losure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCz
iIOziException_heapOverflow_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTe
rmination_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_clo
sure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure" "-Wl,-u,
base_GHCziIOziException_allocationLimitExceeded_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_ControlziE
xceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziEventziThread_blocked
OnBadFD_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure" "-Wl,-u,base
_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_clo
sure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziIO_
ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziIO_ioManagerCapabiliti
esChanged_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure" "-Wl,-u,base_
GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlersPtr_closure" "-lHSbase-4.8.2.0-HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6J
GM" "-lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.0-2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS" "-lHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvW
UcS1U1IKHT0levwg3" "-lHSrts" "-lCffi-6" "-lwsock32" "-luser32" "-lshell32" "-lm"
 "-lwsock32" "-lgdi32" "-lwinmm"
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `wxcorzuLc8buVrXMQOAAoN
jm2eSy1_GraphicsziUIziWXCoreziLayout_zdfWidgetObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_ZCze_con_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziTopLevelWindow_zdfFormObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_set_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziTopLevelWindow_zdfCloseableObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziControls_zdfCommandingObject4_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziEvents_on_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziWindow_zdfTextualObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x27e): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_ZCze_con_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_ZCze_con_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziControls_button_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x427): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziWindow_zdfTextualObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x4b9): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_ZCze_con_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziFrame_frame_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x5da): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWX_start_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x1f8): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziClasses_text_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSl
eeGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziClasses_text_info'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x70): undefined reference to `wxcorzuLc8buVrXMQOAAoN
jm2eSy1_GraphicsziUIziWXCoreziLayout_zdfWidgetObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x78): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziAttributes_set_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x80): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziTopLevelWindow_zdfFormObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x88): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziTopLevelWindow_zdfCloseableObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x90): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziEvents_on_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0x98): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziControls_zdfCommandingObject4_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0xa8): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziWindow_zdfTextualObject_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0xb0): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziControls_button_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0xc8): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWXziFrame_frame_closure'
HelloWorldWX.o:fake:(.data+0xd8): undefined reference to `wxzu6QQu5v1wfyA22ZZSle
eGHgzz_GraphicsziUIziWX_start_closure'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_2.o:ghc_1.c:(.rdata$.refptr
.ZCMain_main_closure[.refptr.ZCMain_main_closure]+0x0): undefined reference to `
ZCMain_main_closure'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_6.rsp C:\Users\pp
77316\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_5.o C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Tem
p\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_4.rc C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_3.r
sp C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_2.o C:\Users\...\App
Data\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0\ghc_1.c
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ghc13152_0
```

I am not really sure why it is having problems finding these references.

I tried executing then with

> runhaskell HelloWorldWX.hs

and received the following error popup from ghc:

[image]

The Verbose flag being set here gives a bunch of information that doesn't really elaborate on any specific problems.

I am running Haskell GHC 7.10.3 full package from Windows Installer to a local Users directory.  I do not have Local Administrator privileges on this workstation but I could try on another machine.

Any clues?  I imagine the first failed install of wxHaskell has corrupted something or I am running into a privilege issue.

Comment: `undefined reference` means usually that linker doesn't have access to proper libraries. Your linker invocation probably lacks something like `-lC:\Users...\Downloads\wxInstall-Achelanne-64-0.1\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll` - a direct request to use your `wxWidgets` library during linkage (more details on linking are here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html)

Comment: @TomaszLewowski I thought just having this folder on the search path was good enough.  Perhaps not.

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Regardless I tried what you suggest and I get the same errors.  I confirm in the verbose output that the -L option is included in the gcc execution for linking.  Whatever it is looking for is not in those libraries

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Thanks for your guidance.  I figured out the issue.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  I forgot that for GHC to create an executable that you need to explicitly specify Cabal packages that you wish to include.  Commenter Tomasz Lewowski was partially correct.  The -L option for linking libraries was required by gcc, however the ghc application intelligently adds ALL the required library paths for a given Cabal package by using the `-package` option.

The second part of making this work was that I needed to compile the .o file specifying -main-is for the main method.  I wrote up the simple batch file and got it working.

```
ghc -v -main-is HelloWorld.main HelloWorld.hs

ghc -v -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.o -package strict-0.3.2 -package wx-0.92.2.0 -package wxc-0.92.2.0 -package wxcore-0.92.2.0 -package wxdirect-0.92.2.0
```

This created the Windows executable just fine and it works like a charm.